# how to get undetect errors software in Windows

Tags: windows

I just got a problem with one of my modem application it called Mobile Connect (I am using Huawei E220 for connect to internet).

yesterday when I was connected to internet, I did accident kill process of the modem using Unlocker (because I want to delete a directory and it write protect by another application, it has nothing to do with Mobile Connect) and then bang .. it doesn't want to show up the application anymore ...

I tried to restart and uninstall and then install again the Mobile Connect .. it won't work.
It has no error message which make me confusing. ... I tried to restore the system to last week Check Points but It wont help as well ...

Is there any tools to detect/fix errors ? 
may be conflicted port or something ? 
any solutions ? I tried to get logs file from c:\program files\huawei\ but it seems there is no log in those directory.

ps: - I am still able to connect to internet using Network Connections (because Mobile Connect create an account for me there).
- I am using Windows XP Pro.
- Mobile Connect is an application that used to connect to Internet (it was made by Huawei modem). I am using Huawei E220 signed by Vodafone, been using it for 1.5 years.
- I have Commodo and Avira on my Windows fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what the process is trying to acess (files, registry and such).